# Receivers Receives Intent several times

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I'm building an app on an android Professional device (not a smartphone or a mobile). I have a problem that drives me crazy..

I've registered my receiver only once. I destroy it when the activity is destroy.

To be sure, before register for it, I've wrapped an "unregisterReceiver" in a "Try and Catch".

But, unfortunately, My intent is sent only once (log confirms that) and my receiver receives it twice.

So how to avoid that?

It runs with Android 10.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple instances of the activity.

Comment: Great, I would not have thought of that. so Where could I register this receiver (It communicates with other apps, so It need to run even if the app is in background) to avoid this instance multiplication?

Comment: "It communicates with other apps, so It need to run even if the app is in background" -- you could register for it in the manifest, and the senders of the broadcast would need to use an explicit `Intent` for the broadcast.